# .ajaxStart and .ajaxStop not firing for some odd reason

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I append a "Loading" class to the body when an ajax request is made so i could then display a progress animation...
For some reason the functions ae never called and I see no alerts...

```
function setLoadingPanel()
{
    var timer;
    var body = $("body");

    alert("Set AJAX HOOKS...");
    $("body").on({
        ajaxStart: function ()
        {
            alert("AJAX START");
            //timer = setTimeout(function () { body.addClass("loading"); }, 50)
        },
        ajaxStop: function ()
        {
            alert("AJAX STOP!!!");
            //$(this).removeClass("loading");
            //clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    });
}
```

I have placed alerts to try and see if the hooks are called but no alert is poping for some reason.

Here is my ajax request using a simple AJAX.ActionLink helper:

```
@{
    var ajaxDialogoptions = new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "DialogContainer",
        OnComplete = "OpenDialog('DialogContainer');"
    };
}
@Ajax.ActionLink(Model.AddNewItemButtonTitle, Model.AddActionName, Model.AddActionController, Model.AddActionRoutValues, ajaxDialogoptions, new { Class = "btn btn-primary anti-align-rtl" })
```

Here is my Bundle of scripts:

```
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle("~/Scripts/jsRTL");

            bundle.AddFile("~/Scripts/Common/jquery-1.9.1.min.js");
            bundle.AddFile("~/Scripts/Common/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js");
            bundle.AddFile("~/Scripts/Common/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js");
            bundle.AddFile("~/Scripts/Validator/jquery.validate.min.js");
            bundle.AddFile("~/Scripts/Validator/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js");
            bundle.AddFile("~/Scripts/Globalize/globalize.js");
            bundle.AddFile("~/Scripts/Globalize/globalize.culture.en-US.js");
            bundle.AddFile("~/Scripts/Globalize/globalize.culture.he.js");
            bundle.AddFile("~/Scripts/Globalize/globalize.culture.he-IL.js");
            bundle.AddFile("~/Scripts/Bootstrap/bootstrap-rtl.js");
            bundle.AddFile("~/Scripts/Common/Common.js");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding the ajaxStart- and ajaxStop-Handler to document like this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    alert("AJAX START");
    //timer = setTimeout(function () { body.addClass("loading"); }, 50)
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    alert("AJAX STOP!!!");
    //$(this).removeClass("loading");
    //clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/):

> As of jQuery 1.8, however, the .ajaxStart() method should only be attached to document.

Answer (score 4):

I notice that you are using jQuery 1.9. Make sure you have upgraded your `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` so that it is compatible with it, because the initial version that shipped with ASP.NET MVC 4 wasn't as it relied on `.live()` which no longer exists.

Comment: Actually you were rigth as well :).. it was outdated and @Philipp M was correct about the $(document) vs. $("body")